# Entity Framework 4: How to enforce WHERE clause order in generated query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Assume the following table `MyObjects`:

```
Id (PK, int)
DecimalField (decimal)
TextField (nvarchar)
```

I have put an additional index on `DecimalField`.

Consider the following LINQ to Entities query to retrieve an object:

```
db.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(r => r.DecimalField == localValue1 && r.TextField == localValue2)
```

Because of the index, it is important that the EF-generated query keeps the order of the properties in the WHERE clause the same (i.e. `DecimalField` first and `TextField` second), otherwise a table scan will occur and the index is useless. How can I enforce EF to keep a certain order in the WHERE clause? And is there a difference between ad hoc and compiled queries?

Comment: KristoferA's answer is correct. To prove it to yourself, write both SQL queries in Management Studio, turn on "Actual Execution Plan", and run the queries. If the two queries don't get exactly the same plan, something is very broken somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the order of where clause predicates does not matter. SQL Server will use the appropriate index if there is one, even if your where clause specifies the columns in a different order than they appear in the index.

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. If SQL Server decides to _not_ use an index, then it is for completely different reasons. E.g. a cached execution plan generated before the index had been created*, outdated statistics for the index, or a query that can be executed more efficiently without using the index.

* = although the plan should be dropped when creating a new index, but sometimes sp_recompile or dbcc freeproccache can be needed anyways.

Comment: sounds good, at least for SQL Server 2005+. But i've had problems with this with SQL Server 2000 in the past.

Comment: Even under SQL 2000 it is was very likely caused by a 'bad' cached execution plan. Changing the order simply forces SQL Server to treat it as a new query and compile it again, and with a bit of luck the new plan is better (due to updated statistics, or SQL Server having enough resources to evaluate more plan options*, or ... ).

* = a server under high load is more likely to come up with a bad plan for complex queries since the optimizer will have less time and resources to choose a plan.